# Difference in memory in Array and Structures?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

What is the difference between memory layout when I allocate some memory like:

```c
float arr[3];
```

and

```c
struct vals {
    float x, y, z;
};
```

I know that when allocating memory in arrays, it is contiguous. But I am confused about the structs... It feels that it will be, and I have tested that with less number of members of structs. an example from raylib [here](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/c0c2e28c1ba0018a23a44d01f0ea4f6145ff626c/src/rlgl.h#L338) also makes me confident. But still, is there any edge cases where the allocated memory is not contiguous or not allocated in the same order of declaration due to some optimization?

Comment: [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member?rq=1)

Comment: As for the order, it's guaranteed that each member of a structure will be placed at an increasing address (see e.g. [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct)). But, as discussed in the question and answers of the link I previously posted, there may be gaps (*padding*) between members.

Comment: Memory ordering of variables would be similar to what has been written in ```struct```, but compilers are free to add ```padding``` bytes to align memory. Usually padding is done on ```4```, ```8```, ```16```, ```32```, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of a struct with consecutive members of the same type, it's *likely* that they will be allocated contiguously in memory but not *guaranteed*.

Also, by the rules of pointer arithmetic, it's valid to do this:

```
*(&arr[0] + 1) = 2.0;
```

But undefined behavior if you do this:

```
struct vals v;
*(&v.x + 1) = 2.0;
```